# Writing XML File blocking access

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, web

I have a web platform with users who write and read a XML file. How can i block users to write on the XML file while another one is doing it? For security, i don't want 2+ users writing the XML file at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the write method.  Read up on it here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

You may want to rethink the design if you have multiple users writing to the same config file.  I expect you'll have lots of problems.  Can you use a database instead?

Comment: Actually, i only have 3 users and i think is not going to be a big problem, also, this XML file provides data to an Android App. I'm going to read your post. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: A simple lock on the write method should work - but if you have two people who want to write, whoever writes second could overwrite the first person's changes.  You'll probably want to notify users that the xml file has changed before allowing them to write so they can review it.